# How to center an element in the center of the screen (without navbar)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Im writting an Angular app, using Angular Material. I want to have a fixed navbar on the top and a main content area below. Something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
            FIXED NAVBAR
---------------------------------------
|                                     |
|         MAIN CONTENT AREA           |
|                                     |
|                                     |
```

In this main content area I want to be able to center a card just in the middle of the main area (not in the middle of the entire web, I dont want to take in account the navbar).

My app.component.html:

```
<mt-toolbar color="primary"></mt-toolbar>

<div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The app.component.css:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 64px;
 }
```

This is my code to the navbar:

HTML

```
<mat-toolbar class="fixed-top" color="primary"></mat-toolbar>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Now, if the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` display a `LoginComponent` that contains only an element, how can I center this element just in the middle of the main area?

Answer (score 1):

```
router-outlet {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: This only centers the content horizontally. I need to center it vertically too.

Comment: Would you mind to use **height: 50vh** for vertically center ?

Comment: Using height: 50vh takes in account the entire viewport and I want to exclude de navbar, to center the element in the main area, not in the entire web page (viewport).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're lokoing for but if you want it staying in that place ( not moving what so ever ) you could make the parent element Position relative and then the item you want centering to be position Absolute then you may get somewhere.
In addition you add

```
.you-class {
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
}
```

If that doesn't work try do:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Maybe [this will help](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on the element you vertically want to center.

Use `display: table` on the parent.